# Mysql merge two varchar columns delete duplicate words

Tags: mysql, sql, merge

I have table with 2 varchar columns - col_name1 and col_name2 PLUS empty varchar col_name3

```
(1, 'hello world', 'hello test', ''),
(2, 'hello from my sql fiddle', 'hello my sql', '');
```

See [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/942f8/1)

I'm looking for a way to merge two varchar columns into one but delete duplicate words.
It means a new col_name3 should contain only unique words like below

```
(1, 'hello world', 'hello test', 'world test'),
(2, 'hello from my sql fiddle', 'hello my sql', 'from fiddle');
```

Comment: @Mihai I remember you were good with similar solutions, may be have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/50429292/2637838

Comment: I think by mistake you pasted the link for the same question.

Comment: If you want to delete duplicates, you probably have the wrong data structure.  Your "'words" are probably more like "keywords" or "tags" and should be in a separate association/junction table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for question:

```
select id,group_concat(words) output
from(
SELECT id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.col, ' ', x.cifre), ' ', -1) AS words
,count(1)
FROM (SELECT id,concat(col_name1,' ',col_name2,' ',col_name3) as col FROM table_name) t
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 1 + a.i + b.i * 10  cifre, b.i + a.i * 10  sute
    FROM (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) a
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) b
) x
ON (LENGTH(t.col) +1 - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.col, ' ', ''))) >= x.cifre
group by id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.col, ' ', x.cifre), ' ', -1)
having count(1) =1) s
where length(words) > 0
group by id
```

Output:

```
id  output
1   test,world
2   fiddle,from
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/942f8/27

Comment: I'd like to give +100 ! Excellent smart solution ! ...is it possible to keep whitespace instead of comma in output ?

Comment: Yes, you can just replace "," with space, I replaced here you can check out.     http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/942f8/39

Comment: Yes, now it's finally ! THX !

Comment: May I ask - is it possible to modify your amazing solution at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/942f8/39 to find the duplicate words and DELETE them from col_name1 ? If you have a solution I can publish this as a new question.

Comment: Yes, we can do that

Comment: I have the solution for it, but I need time around 5-6 hour to finish my dead lines.

Comment: thank you for your attention, please, take your time, I'll wait as more as need.